# Jackson Deserialize String remove \n

Tags: java, json, jackson

We have a front call api with a json containing a String with carriage return "\n".

But, when the java spring application get it after deserialization, all \n has disappeared.

Can you help me pls ?

The JSON Send :

```
{
...
    description: "Line \nNewLine1\n\nNewLine2"
...
}
```

The API

```
enter code here
    @PutMapping("/v1/myapi")
public MyDTO save(@RequestBody MyDTO myDTO) {
    return this.myService.save(myDTO);
}
```

The DTO :

```
@ApiModel(description = "DTO ")
public class MyDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ApiModelProperty(value = "L'id")
private Long id;


@Size(max = 4000)
@ApiModelProperty(value = "La description")
private String description;
```

The DTO content after deserialization

```
description = "Line NewLine1 NewLine2"
```

Comment: Do you have any custom preprocessing or filters which could remove new line character? By default it should stay. Which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: In our configuration we have "jackson: serialization.indent_output: true" and we have also XSS protection in spring boot for prevent from injection ...

Comment: `indent_output` is used only during serialisation process. I would set a breakpoint in "XSS protection" module and debug it, maybe there is a logic which removes new lines. You can always create a demo project using `Spring` and `Jackson` in versions you use in your real project and try to test out this behaviour. If in demo new lines are preserved it means in your business project there is a customisation which removes them.